# Base Converter(from any to any)

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to make a base converter, which can convert any number from one base to another. My program should work correctly if 2 conditions are kept(0>number<4*(10**9); 1>base<37). I have spent some hours and I lost the reason why it works wrong. All result numbers are printed correctly, if they does not include any symbols from A to Z. So, how I can fix it to make my program work correctly?
Parameter base in function int is not allowed to use.Check my code below:

```
import numpy as np

def change_base(originNum, base1, base2):
    alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    a = np.zeros((1, len(originNum)))
    for i in range(len(originNum)): #identify all chars in num
        for j in range(len(alphabet)):
            if alphabet[j] == originNum[i]:
                a[0][i] += j

    for x in range(a.size):  #convert num to dec
        a[0][-(x+1)] *= (base1**x)

    convertedNum = int(np.sum(a)) #num in dec base

    convertedNum2 = [] #empty num in second base
    while convertedNum > 0:
        convertedNum2.append((convertedNum % base2))
        convertedNum//=base2
        if convertedNum <= base2:
            convertedNum2.append((convertedNum % base2))
            convertedNum //= base2
            break

    # print(convertedNum2)
    result = []
    for y in range(len(convertedNum2)):
        for z in range(len(alphabet)):
            if str(convertedNum2[y]) == alphabet[z]:
                result.append(alphabet[z])
    print(result)

originNum = input()
base1 = int(input())
base2 = int(input())
change_base(originNum, base1, base2)
# print(change_base(str, base1, base2))
# alphabet = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Comment: Python have the bin() function that convert any number to binary, hex() convert any number to hexadecimal and int() convert any number to decimal. You can use them instead of writing one from scratch and your program will be less error prone

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? There are two steps, have you checked that the number you get is correct after the first conversion?